# How to Save Multiple User Metadata in Database?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I am trying to create a registration form ([here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-registration-forms/)) with the help of a free plugin.
There are many elements in the registration form.
In the admin panel, meta keys can be assigned for each element in the plugin interface. So there is such an opportunity.
I'm trying to collect many of the elements on the same meta key by taking advantage of this possibility. In this direction, I gave the common meta key value to the elements I created. For example: info_about_register
So far everything is fine. However, if the form is posted, I can only get the last entry in the usermeta table. So the plugin is not serializing the same meta key data. An array does not occur.

There are many form elements. I want to pull these to the admin panel later. Therefore, I think that defining a separate line for each element will tire the system a lot. I contacted the plugin developers about this issue. However, no response for about 1.5 weeks.
I tried to solve this problem myself and found the codes where the action was taken. I made some changes to these. However, I was not successful. I would be very happy if you guide me.

[.../includes/class-frontend.php](http://jdoodle.com/a/3HtQ)

```
 /*
     * Called after submission save
     * Registers new user into WordPress.
     * Also map field values to user meta (If configured)
     */
public function after_submission_insertion($errors, $submission, $data) {
    $sub_model = erforms()->submission;
    $form_model = erforms()->form;
    $form = $form_model->get_form($submission['form_id']);
    
    // Copy attachment values in data from submission (as $data does not have any uploaded file values)
    if(!empty($submission['attachments'])){
        foreach($submission['attachments'] as $attachment){
            if(!isset($data[$attachment['f_name']])){
                $data[$attachment['f_name']]= $attachment['f_val'];
            }
        }
    }
 if ($form['type'] == "reg") { // Handling of registration forms
            $user = 0;
            $id = 0;
            // Get mapping for user meta fields if any
            $user_field_map = erforms_filter_user_fields($form['id'], $submission['fields_data']);
            // Avoid user registration process if user already logged in
            if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
                $email_or_username = $user_field_map['user_email'];

                if (isset($user_field_map['password'])) {
                    // Silently creates user  
                    $username = isset($user_field_map['username']) ? $data[$user_field_map['username']] : $data[$email_or_username];
                    do_action('erf_before_user_creation',$submission);
                    $id = wp_create_user($username, $data[$user_field_map['password']], $data[$email_or_username]);
                } else {
                    // Register user and sends random password via email notification
                    do_action('erf_before_user_creation',$submission);
                    $id = register_new_user($data[$email_or_username], $data[$email_or_username]);
                }

                if (is_wp_error($id)) {
                    // In case something goes wrong delete the submission
                    wp_delete_post($submission['id'], true);
                    $error_code = $id->get_error_code();
                    if ($error_code == 'existing_user_login') {
                        $email_or_username = 'username_error';
                    }

                    $errors[] = array($email_or_username, $id->get_error_message($id->get_error_code()));
                    return $errors;
                } else {
                    $selected_role = erforms_get_selected_role($submission['form_id'], $data);
                    if (!empty($selected_role)) { // Means user has selected any role
                        $user_model = erforms()->user;
                        $selected_role= apply_filters('erf_before_setting_user_role',$selected_role,$id,$form, $submission);
                        $user_model->set_user_role($id, $selected_role);
                    }
                    foreach ($user_field_map as $req_key => $meta_key) {
                        $is_primary_key = in_array($meta_key, erforms_primary_field_types());
                        if (isset($data[$req_key]) && !$is_primary_key) {
                            $m_keys= explode(',',$meta_key);
                            foreach($m_keys as $m_key){
                                if(!empty($m_key)){
                                    $status = erforms_update_user_meta($id, $m_key, $data[$req_key]);
                                    do_action('erf_user_meta_updated',$m_key,$id,$data[$req_key],$status);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    do_action('erf_user_created', $id, $form['id'], $submission['id']);
                }
            } else {
                // Get user details
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                $id = $user->ID;
                
                foreach ($user_field_map as $req_key => $meta_key) {
                    $is_primary_key = in_array($meta_key, erforms_primary_field_types());
                    if (isset($data[$req_key]) && !$is_primary_key) {
                        $m_keys= explode(',',$meta_key);
                        foreach($m_keys as $m_key){
                            if(!empty($m_key)){
                                $status= erforms_update_user_meta($id,$m_key,$data[$req_key]);
                                do_action('erf_user_meta_updated',$m_key,$id,$data[$req_key],$status);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

//...

     // User meta,URL params or default values should be prefilled only when we are not loading submission data
        if(empty($submission)){
            $user_meta = erforms()->user->frontend_localize_user_meta($form);
            $filtered_url_params = array();
            foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
                $filtered_url_params[urldecode(strtolower(wp_unslash($key)))] = sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($val));
            }

            $url_keys = array_keys($filtered_url_params);
            foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
                $label = !empty($field['label']) ? strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $field['label'])) : '';
                $label = str_replace('&', 'and', $label); // Cause URL params do not allow & 
                if (!empty($field['name']) && !empty($label) && in_array($label, $url_keys)) {
                    if (!isset($user_meta[$field['name']]) && !empty($filtered_url_params[$label])) {
                        $user_meta[$field['name']] = stristr($filtered_url_params[$label], '|') ? explode('|', $filtered_url_params[$label]) : $filtered_url_params[$label];
                    }
                }
                if(!empty($field['name']) && empty($user_meta[$field['name']]) && !empty($field['value'])){
                    $user_meta[$field['name']] = $field['value'];
                }
                
            }

            if (!empty($user_meta)) {
                $data['user_meta'] = $user_meta;
            }
        }
        $data= apply_filters('erf_form_localize_data',$data,$form);
        return $data;
    }
```

[.../includes/functions.php](http://jdoodle.com/a/3HtL)

```
/**
 * Wrapper to call update_user_meta function. 
 * This simply calls wordpress meta function and does not add any special prefix. 
 * Checks for any special meta key to update user table data. 
 * For example: display_name : updates user's display name. Instead of adding display_name usermeta
 */
function erforms_update_user_meta($user_id, $m_key, $m_val) {
    switch ($m_key) {
        case 'display_name' : $status = wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, $m_key => $m_val));
            return is_wp_error($status) ? false : true;
    }
    return update_user_meta($user_id, $m_key, $m_val);
}
```

Comment: 1st never edit core files since on next update you will lose em. Use this hook on submit wp_insert_user and add_user_meta to add your meta. Read this - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/ and this - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know these functions.
If I find the solution I will try to handle it with hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Data can be stored as an array with a definition like below. Also, the key values ($all_meta_value[$req_key]) are equal to the id, name values automatically assigned to the HTML elements by the plugin.
Using this, different conditional states can be written.

*The following code must be defined in the function.php file in the child theme:*

```
add_action('erf_user_meta_updated','for_new_user_meta_uptated',10);
    function for_new_user_meta_uptated($data){
    //if the defined meta key (info_about_register) matches 
    if($m_key == 'info_about_register'){
        $all_meta_value[$req_key] = $data;
        }
    }
add_action('erf_user_created', 'for_new_user_created',10);
function for_new_user_created($id){
    //Save the values as a new user meta
    add_user_meta($id, 'new_info_about_register', $get_meta_value);
    
    //Remove saved single element user meta. 
    delete_user_meta($id, 'info_about_register');
}
```